# Installing Python on RHEL6.9 - No Internet, No Yum, No Pip

Tags: python, installation, python-3.6

I have a super barebones airgapped machine.

It has the Python3.6.6.tar.gz from the website.  It has no access to outside sources. It has no ability to use yum or pip as they're not on here.

What is the best method for getting Python3.6 installed onto here without having to transfer files over?

Edit -

I've tried

```
./configure
make ( or make install or make altinstall )
```

When I go to run python3.6 I get

```
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'
```

I've tried changing export PYTHONHOME to /usr/local/ with no luck, though that did clear up a previous error related to it

Comment: What's in that `.tar.gz` file? Source code? An RPM? A zip containing precompiled binaries?

Comment: Several folders (build, Doc, Grammar, Mac, Lib, Object, Modules, Include, etc) and files (config.log, config.sub, configure, libpython3.6m.a, Makefile, setup.py, README.rst ) to name a few.

Comment: I guess I technically asked what's in the file, but what I meant was "what _is_ it"? What does "the Python3.6.6.tar.gz from the website" mean? From what website? What did you _try_ to download? And what does the `README.rst` say?

Comment: My bad. From python.org. Its the install for Linux located here https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-366/ .  The readme contains instructions, including "to install, do ./configure, make, make test, sudo make install", but I've had no luck.

Comment: Okay, so it looks like source code and you've updated your question with more information. Does `./configure` succeed? Does `make` succeed? `make` and `make install` aren't alternatives; `make` needs to succeed before you can `make install`.